# If questions about how to construct malicious software do not require moderator attention, then what does?

Tags: discussion

**NOTES**

As I had already made quite clear in this question, I knew the other question might have been for legitimate research/academic reasons, but I just wanted somebody to check on it in case.  I exaggerated my suspicion a little bit in the description behind my flag.

Also, I've accepted Bill the Lizard's answer, but I want to note that something was lost in translation in the reason I gave for the flag.  I knew it could have been asked for academic purposes, but I didn't think of that sort of thing as being as common on this kind of site as other users have.  If it's more common than I thought, I can see why the flag got rejected.

But there was a little bit said about it missing any detail of what I wanted the moderators to do about it.  I think between me probably not proofreading it - and me previously thinking of such academic questions and uses as being  more unusual than other folks did - I didn't actually say in the description that I wanted the *intent* to be checked on.  I thought it was understood.  But when I look back at the description that was typed, now I see that wasn't very clear.

And I know it's certainly difficult to verify something like that, but I was just taking a shot in the dark.

---

Yesterday I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776198/create-an-exception-for-firewall-vb-net), which is fairly suspicious.  The user's app is named "Essayagevirus", and he is asking a question about how to break through a firewall in .NET code.

Please understand that I realize that this seems rather out in the open, for it to be somebody who is actually trying to do something evil.  It would be pretty foolish of them to not try to hide it more. So there's definitely a chance there's more to the story, but I just felt the need to flag it for a moderator to just check on it and try to see.

The flag was rejected, and the reason seems fairly awkward:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

?  This doesn't say the moderator checked on it and felt that nothing was wrong; it says the moderator felt like it just doesn't apply to them.

I'm not saying it was necessarily an attempt to do something malicious, but it was suspicious enough that I felt that somebody just needed to check on it.  But if reasonably suspected attempts of people trying to get help constructing viruses don't count as something that needs moderator attention, then what does?

**EDIT**

One thing that's come up from a couple of different people is that I didn't specifically tell the moderator what I was wanting to do.  But I'm not sure why this is a big deal.  I said that I didn't want to jump to conclusions, but the question did look suspicious for being asked with malicious intent.

At work, if a client tells us one of our programs had problems over the weekend, doesn't that mean that they want us to check on it, see what happened, and do what's needed?

I can follow that moderators probably don't want to ban this kind of question entirely, as it can be for legitimate reasons.  Part of the reason I said I didn't want to jump to conclusions is that I understood yesterday that this could have been for legitimate uses, even if it was a virus.  And that may justify the given reason on its own...but I don't follow the other.

Comment: Screenshot [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P4azY.png), in case it gets deleted, for those who don't have 10k.

Comment: Bit of a horse shoe to make the name of his program visible :)  Programmers like that are not dangerous, just inept.  Highly selective for a student doing a security related assignment.

Comment: A virus? In VB.Net? That made my day.

Comment: I know that's a weird language choice, and I've said that I suspected there was more to the story.

Comment: To add to the drama, apparently they were allowed to edit the app name and remove "virus".

Comment: @KennethVogt Is that an insult?

Comment: No, I was noting that you said the app name was "Essayagevirus" but has been edited to now say "Essayage".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you flag with the "Other" reason, please leave a detailed message about what is wrong and *what action* should be taken.

Your flag:

> The Blue Dog left a comment to this effect on the question, but I don't know if it's been reported. I don't want to jump to conclusions, but given things like the name of his program and what he's trying to get help with, we are all very suspicious that the OP is trying to construct a virus.

That tells a moderator that you're suspicious, but it doesn't say what you think they should do about it. People can write viruses for legitimate research purposes, and they're perfectly welcome to ask about it on Stack Overflow. (Encouraged to, really. I'd rather people did that sort of thing out in the open so we all know about it.) Moderators don't need to be notified of it, as it's really not that uncommon.

Comment: Somebody also posted something in the comments about the moderator not knowing what I wanted them to do about it, which they've deleted.  I follow what you're saying about legitimate uses, but why would the moderator need me to tell them explicitly what I wanted them to do about it?

Comment: @Panzercrisis Because we don't know what you want us to do? Should we delete a question just for asking about viruses?

Comment: @Panzercrisis Part of the reason you need to detail what you want the mods to do is because the flags get used for more than just deleting posts.  For example, if someone is repeatedly promoting a product in answers without disclosing their affiliation, a recommended action is to flag for mod attention and explain what is going on so the mod can investigate and take an appropriate action (which may or may not include deleting things).

Comment: When people raise flags that say, "There may or may not be an issue here, but it's a little suspect," it just seems like common sense would say that they want it to be checked on and verified.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Ok, what does "checked on and verifed" mean? You want us to look at it and verify that the user is indeed writing a virus? Ok, done. What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: I thought it was understood that I wanted the moderator to *try and see* if they could tell if *malicious **intent*** were involved.  If that couldn't be confirmed, no harm done.  If it could be confirmed, then it's malicious intent, not just a research question.  I was just saying, "Please see if this user truly is trying to use this site for something evil, or if everything is actually alright."  I wasn't sure if anything could have been confirmed, but just in case it could have been, it would have been whatever the moderator decided to do in response.

Comment: There is nothing malicious in the entire question or code at all... Not can moderators possibly know the **intent** of said code / user. And no we don't have Jason Bourne on the mod team.

Answer (score 3):

I have made a similar mistake before. The trick is to remember that Stack Overflow is a code assistance service, **not** a law enforcement/morality police service. A question should only be removed if it doesn't follow the SO guidelines.